# Spark maximum query size

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using either the DataFrame API (`df.groupby('id').sum()`) or Spark SQL (`spark.sql('select * from tableA')`) we can build complex queries. I'm writing some code that leverages `CASE`/`when()` and I recall that there's a limit to Spark's query size.

I assume there is a size limit to both a Spark Job and a Spark Stage. By "size limit" I mean the length of the instruction that can be submitted / stored / evaluated / distributed etc. The RDBMS equivalent would be a maximum query length, e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131399/is-there-a-maximum-length-constraint-for-a-postgres-query

What's the maximum query size / length in Spark? I have seen it hit before back in `1.3` or `1.5`, but (a) can't find it, and (b) it's probably outdated anyway. Is this limit determined by the datatype which stores the DAG?

Comment: +1. Did you ever find the answer to this? I am in a similar predicament: dynamically creating long conditionals at runtime and concerned about what'll happen in production when my users throw unexpectedly long searches at it.

Comment: Hey Eric. I never bothered - will be in the Spark source somewhere. I first encountered this on an older version (~1.6) and it was a substantial query size, in megabytes.